# What is the difference between "@attr = ..." and "attr := ..." on class attributes?

Tags: oz, mozart

The text book for my class warns not to mix up `@attr = ...` and `attr := ...` when working with class attributes. It does not, however, explain what the difference is. I know that when working with cells, `MyCell := ...` changes the contents of the cell, but I have never seen `@something = ...`.

Comment: Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C={NewCell 4}
@C=3
{Browse @C}
```

The code above outputs nothing, because @C=3 is the same as

```
{Cell.access C $}=3
```

and as the function {Cell.access C $} return 4, it is the same as

```
4=3
```

To assign a new value to a Cell, you must use `:='

Comment: To a cell, yes. But does the same go for class attributes? Are they just cells? Also, wouldn't `{Browse @C}` output 4, since the previous assignment did nothing?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it's the same. So they might be cells :p

Comment: (http://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/base/node14.html#chapter.infix)
give an element of response. It's not the same as a cell, but it works kind of the same way